# Dealing with map in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a map in a UIPageViewController. This map has overlays in it. My setup has two pages. The left one is a UIViewController with a map in it and the right one is a UICollectionViewController.

The app opens on the right view.

The issue is that when I swipe to open the left view, the app freezes for one to two seconds and then opens the map view controller. This is a problem.

How can I get the UI to remain responsive when opening the map for the first time?

Comment: show some code. Can't predict the issue

Comment: Yeah could be your `MapView` is doing networking on the main thread but without seeing some code in your viewController it is hard to tell.

Comment: @NSGangster, I’ll post the code once I get home. Your guess would make sense because I recall getting yelled at in the console about thread stuff.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS, it's actually laggy *whenever* I present a view controller with an MKMapView. Even in a modal presentation vc